# Custom Data Set - Saves but does will not display

Tags: custom-fields, error

I created a custom data set of type Tab with Table that accepts multiple entries, and I have added this to the New Individual form.

I can then create a new individual and hit save, after which time the Tab with the custom data fields is displayed. I can enter data into the custom data fields and save it.  After I save, the count displays that it has been created, but nothing appears in the list/table except a message that says "No records of type '' found."

Is this a bug?

Comment: I just played around with the settings and changed it to tab (not tab with table), went to the contact record and all of the data displayed fine.  I then changed it back to Tab with Table and got the original error message again -  "No records of type '' found." - so there appears to be an error with the Tab with Table functionality.  How does one raise a bug for this?

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem. My CiviCRM 4.7.25 *(sequentially upgraded from 4.7.18)* was on Joomla 3.8.1 *(also sequentially upgraded from 3.7.x)*. After doing some observation in the database, I noticed that the field named **in_selector** *(table: civicrm_custom_field)* was **0**. When I manually changed the values from 0 to 1 using **PHPMyAdmin**, I got the **Tab with Table** listing to work. Upon further investigation, I believe the respective individual fields' setting **Display in Table** needs to be ticked/true.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It solved the issue for me. I think it had happened because when I created the new custom group, I forgot to select Tab with Table. It was only after I created the fields that I went back to change it to a multi-value group field (ie selecting Tab with Table).

Comment: I had exactly the same issue today and this solved it for me.  Unless you really know what you are doing it is quite dangerous to go directly into the CiviCRM database and make changes like this.  ALWAYS back up your database before doing anyting like this.  The best option is the final paragraph - go to each individual field in the set and click on the 'Display in Table' option.  This is there to allow configuration of the view of those data columns.  You can also achieve the same result by using the API explorer and updating the values. Again, back up the database first!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug, which version of CiviCRM are you using? Which version of which CMS are you using?

Can you repeat it on 
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org
or
http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org
?

Comment: Thanks! CiviCRM 4.7.11 & WordPress 4.6.1.
I will attempt to reproduce when I get back to the office in a couple of days and update this record accordingly.

Comment: I just tested this on the wpmaster version and it works - weird!

Comment: Then it is unfortunately likely a bug related to the setup of your system. Could be the CiviCRM extensions or even a WordPress plugin.

Best way to approach would be to create a copy of your install and then switch extensions and plugins off to see if one of them is causing it.

Let us know if you found it.